# UI Terminology: Logon vs Login

Tags: user-interface, terminology

I am crafting an application and cannot decide whether to use the terms **Login/out** or **Logon/off**. Is there a *more correct* option between these two? Should I use something else entirely (like "Sign on/off").

In terms of usability, as long as I am consistent it probably doesn't matter which terms I choose, but I did wonder about the origins of the terms - and whether one or another makes more grammatical sense. I also care deeply about the application I am creating, and want to take the time to investigate all aspects of its user experience.

Comment: +1, not only for your concern about usability, but also for starting a fascinating conversation.  Thank you!

Comment: There exists a fourth alternative as "Sign in/Out" as well ;)

Comment: Interesting side note, although it doesn't answer your question.  The Latin word "in" (from which we get the English word "in") means both "in" and "on".

Comment: Sign* is my preferred way: "Sign Up", "Sign In" and "Sign Out", I may use the term "Username" if such needed within the system (email is not used as a credential) and not "User Name" to emphasis the "PaulSmith" rather than "Paul Smith" (the full name)

Comment: I have wondered about this same question - everytime while building apps with authentication. Good that you asked! :)

Comment: Another interesting discussion on SO makes the front page of Hacker News (http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4249097). It can only be a matter of minutes before it's shut down by the mods.

Comment: **Related:** [Using “Sign in” vs using “Log in”](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/using-sign-in-vs-using-log-in) on [User Experience Stack Exchange](http://ux.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Well I just did my part in reopening it. If the rules don't allow for useful questions, please change the rules.

Comment: @MattJoiner This may be useful, but it's not on topic. It's relevant to programmers, but it's not a programming question -- this is a user experience or language question. Appropriately, [the equivalent question on the User Experience site is still open](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/using-sign-in-vs-using-log-in).

Comment: @JeremyBanks: Create a user-experience tag, don't clone the site. Asking a tech question shouldn't require 15 mins searching for the correct SE site on which to ask it. Especially when several such sites apply.

Comment: Using just "Enter" and "Leave" could cut grammatical confusion.

Comment: @MattJoiner **Stack Overflow isn't for "tech" questions, it's for programming questions.** Questions that were only *relevant* to programmers were tolerated when the site was young. The unintended consequence was that questions that had nothing to do with programming ended up being *more popular* than the actual programming questions! The site was clearly going downhill, and the current strict moderation is a necessary response to that. Communities that can't keep their focus end up dying or turning into Reddit.

Comment: It is funny to hear people argue about the validity of a question on this site.  Your comments have nothing to do with coding or programming and add nothing to the conversation.  Now I am guilty of the same thing.

Comment: Verb forms would be sign in, sign on, log in, log on, sign off, sign out, log off, and log out.  Noun forms would be sign-in, sign-on, login, logon, sign-off, sign-out, logoff, and logout.

Answer (score 292, accepted):

Since you're looking for correctness,

*login*, *logout*, *logon*, and *logoff* are all **nouns**:

```
"Please enter your login credentials."
"I see three logons but only two logoffs from this user."
```

The corresponding **verbs** are each two words:

```
"Please log in to see your reputation."
"You must log off and talk to a human."
```

---

Update:  according to [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/login), the various definitions of *login* are all nouns and involve gaining access to a *computer* or *computer service*.  Interestingly, *logon* redirects to *login* as an exact equivalent.  Have the definitions evolved?

Comment: This has irked me as well.  You can also consider login as an adjective: Please enter your login information below.

Comment: @strager: Yes, thanks for the catch.  Don't even get me started on "doing things everyday" ... which is now apparently correct enough to appear on TV, in signage, and everywhere else except in a dictionary.

Comment: Very interesting - it does look like the terms are both converging and evolving.

Comment: @strager Sure, but that's really in the same way that many nouns can be used as adjectives.

salad: "I need a new salad bowl"
fan: "The fan blades have a lot of dust"
payment: "Please enter your payment information"
shoe: "Those left shoe marks!"

It's safe to simply say that "login" is a noun.

Comment: @strager FYI, grammatically speaking, those aren't considered adjectives, but rather noun adjuncts. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct

Comment: Logon was early usage, I think it started to get replaced by login in the late 90s when the Web took off.

Answer (score 90):

Voice of democracy: term / number of google results:

```
login    2,020,000,000
sign in    430,000,000
logon       27,700,000
log on      18,200,000
```

```
logout      83,500,000
log out     34,500,000
sign out    19,400,000
log off      5,350,000
```

Comment: I wouldn't count on Google for this kind of thing: `I could care less` 30,100,000, `I couldn't care less` 19,700,000

Comment: True that: I couldnt care less 113,000,000

Comment: @robmcm: use quotes; "I couldnt care less" only finds about 1,450,000 results.

Comment: @EamonNerbonne That's because you spelled it wrong.

Comment: "log in" is missing from the list

Comment: -1 I don't consider Google's tailored per user search results a "democracy".

Comment: `I could(n't) care less` communicates a lack of concern that is embellished by skipping the `n't`.

Comment: @highwind7777 `I could care less` <> `I couldn't care less`. The latter states an utter lack of caring. The former states that you do in fact care, as there is an amount less that it is possible to care.

Comment: @dasil003: that's because I was trying to replicate robmcm's results; which were also misspelled.

Comment: @BiggAl I think that highwind7777 understands the difference, but was making a joke around the thought that someone who "couldn't care less" might care _so little_ that they don't care about phrasing or grammar either, and that is why they say "I could care less" instead.

Comment: Henceforth I shall use login and logout.

Answer (score 57):

**Logon** is used for a hardware system that starts up when used, like a computer.

**Login** is used for a software system where I have to enter my username and password.

**Signin** is used for identification, either physical such as a photo ID, or digital such as OpenID. What differs here from **login** is that in the case of an ID, I can use the same ID to access multiple sites, buildings, etc.

*Edit 1: I should've added a disclaimer that I have no sources and make no guarantee that these are the official usage of the words. The definitions I'm offering about are based on my personal understanding of the usage, and are purely opinion.*

Comment: The explanations for login/logon "feel" right, but I'm not sure about signin -- is this convention or "officially correct" usage?  What about signon?  Thanks for the info!

Comment: You have a source for this? I've never heard this distinction between logon/login before, and I've worked with hardware and software for a long time.

Perhaps this is localle/industry specific?

Comment: @Adam: Signing on is a colloquial term for collecting unemployment benefit [or Job Seeker's allowance now] in the UK, so that may not be so good there.

Comment: Sorry. I just added a disclaimer that I make no guarantees that the above definitions are "officially correct" usage.

Comment: @balabaster: Funny, in the US, signing on means joining a company, and some offer a sign-on bonus, which is simply extra cash up front for joining.

Comment: Most of the uses I've seen of "sign" involve a recognizable pubic identity - especially in chat and so on.  System accounts don't have a specific person, and anon accounts notionally don't either - I just don't hear "sign on as root", but only the "log in" variations.  Sign on also sounds a bit more privacy-compromising.

Comment: I agree that "sign" words imply an official identity: signing up could mean enlisting in the army; signing on - in the UK - is claiming unemployment benefit; signing off is what you do at the end of a letter or a broadcast, or to validate documents such as proposals or payments; at my workplace visitors have to sign in when they enter the building and sign out when they leave. Most of these actions require a signature and at least one of them can get you killed. In short, not good for accessing computer systems.

Comment: I've seen higher conversion rates for using "Sign Up/In/Out". I can't remember what I read about the "log in vs sign in" but it did state that psychologically you are more apt to click the sign in than log in because it is less intrusive. In all reality, it's like arguing whitespace for indentation

Answer (score 28):

with spaces:
[http://google.com/trends/explore?q="log in","log on","sign in","sign on"](http://google.com/trends/explore?q=%22log%20in%22%2C%22log%20on%22%2C%22sign%20in%22%2C%22sign%20on%22)
winner: "sign in"

no spaces:
http://google.com/trends/explore?q=login,logon,signin,signon
winner: login

spaces vs no spaces:
[http://google.com/trends/explore?q="sign in",login](http://google.com/trends/explore?q=%22sign%20in%22%2Clogin)
winner: **login**

---

with spaces:
[http://google.com/trends/explore?q="log out","log off","sign out","sign off"](http://google.com/trends/explore?q=%22log%20out%22%2C%22log%20off%22%2C%22sign%20out%22%2C%22sign%20off%22)
winner: "log off"

no spaces:
http://google.com/trends/explore?q=logout,logoff,signout,signoff
winner: logout

spaces vs no spaces:
[http://google.com/trends?q="log off",logout](http://google.com/trends/explore?q=%22log%20off%22%2Clogout)
winner: **logout**

Comment: I did a survey off all the top sites in alexa, almost without exception, social networking sites use "Login", all other sites (portals and email etc) use sign in.

If AOL says sign in and that's what their users understand, then go with that since I'd say that is the LCD

Comment: Popularity does not mean authority or correctness...

Comment: I am most interested in what happened Q4 2011 that saw the strong decrease in the use of 'sign in', whilst there was a slightly slower but just as strong increase in the use of 'log in'.

Even more interesting is that the apparent correlation almost disappears when you look at any region in isolation; it seems to be an almost exclusively global trend.

Comment: People may tend to write more about "the for sale *sign in* their yard" than about "who left the *log in* the bowl?" I think adding [password](http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=%22log%20in%22%20password%2C%20%22log%20on%22%20password%2C%20%22sign%20in%22%20password%2C%20%22sign%20on%22%20password&cmpt=q) brings us closer to the trend OP is interested in.

Comment: This is dangerously close to a link-only answer. Results from these searches should be summarized or embedded as a screenshot. Search statistics from 2009 are vastly different from the 2017 results those links currently point to.

Answer (score 14):

My preferences (less popular, but many cool websites are using this convention):

```
[Sign In] [Join]

Welcome, UserName! [Sign Out]
```

I wouldn't use any of the following: Log On, Logon, Log In, Log Out

Another option is (which is by the way more popular):

```
[Login] [Register]

Welcome, UserName! [Logout]
```

Google Stats (hits):

```
[Sign In], [Sign Out] -> 1 210 000 000 + 300 700 000 = 1 510 700 000
[Login], [Logout]     -> 1 940 000 000 + 88 200 000  = 2 028 200 000
[Log In], [Log Out]   -> 873 000 000   + 83 800 000  =   956 800 000
```

[Sign Up] for registration link is also a good option but it does't look good near [Sign In], you should use it wether with [Login] or seporatly.

[Sign In] [Join] on a page looks more user-friendly (less official) for me than [Login] [Register]

Answer (score 8):

Microsoft's framework design guidelines recommmend using "LogOn" rather than "LogIn" but "SignIn" rather than "SignOn" (see [rule CA1726](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182258.aspx) from FxCop's code analysis). Granted this is talking about framework/API naming conventions, but it's worth putting out there for people to consider.

Comment: I'd summarily discount any term in CamelCase, which reeks of, um, MadeUpness.  I'm afraid I'm turning into Andy Rooney.

Comment: Yeah, but the framework design guidelines are about identifiers in code rather than UI. Still, I thought it was worth bringing up purely for the "on" vs "in" debate.

Answer (score 6):

I've always distinguished the two in this manner:

Logon - you log on to a terminal or other multi-user access DEVICE
Login - you log in to an SOFTWARE application, either for authorization or authentication

although obviously, there is a lot of overlap between the two, especially since terminals aren't so common anymore.  But as you say, it probably doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an old thread about this problem: "[Logon vs Login](http://discuss.fogcreek.com/joelonsoftware/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=19480)"
Personally I think that you should use terminology your users are most familiar with. For Windows platform "logon" seems to be a common term.

Interesting fact: Google yields 2.040.000.000 results for "[login](http://www.google.ru/search?q=login)" and 27.400.000 for "[logon](http://www.google.ru/search?q=logon)".

Comment: I guess one can conclude login is preferable on the Web.

Comment: yep, seems that login is the most popular term

Comment: Windows is also "starting up" (why not just "starting"?) and requires you to click "Start" to shut down.  I agree that "login" seems more popular; "logon" seems somehow dated.

Comment: @AdamLiss without the "up" you can't use Rolling Stones for branding ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I have to say, that I looked into that Q and usually: *Login, Logon, Logoff* or *Log in, Log on, Log off* are used in **applied applications**.

Such verbs & nouns like *Sign in, Join, Sign out, Sign up* are more used in **web applications**, but as it was said earlier it all comes down to personal preference...

Answer (score 4):

If only all problems were so easy to solve as trying to decide which grammar is "more correct".  I think this is one of those that comes down to personal preference...

I personally prefer Login/Logout, but I know lots of software that uses Logon/Logoff.

Answer (score 4):

Several answers compare the popularity based on Google results, where *Log in/out* is clearly the winner. I don't think this should be used as a guide though.

Both Windows Live ID and Google Accounts (the two most used authentication systems?) use *Sign in/out* on their user interfaces. Interestingly, both use *Login* on their URLs (`https://login.live.com/login.srf`, `https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin`).

My conclusion is that *Log in/out* are more popular amongst developers for historical reasons (they are used in framework APIs, etc.), and for that they continue to use it (e.g. this very site, stackoverflow.com), but end users are probably more familiar with *Sign in/out*.

---

Same with Yahoo and AOL, *Sign in/out* on user interfaces, *Login* on URLs (`https://login.yahoo.com/config/login_verify2`, `https://my.screenname.aol.com/_cqr/login/login.psp`).

Answer (score 0):

I think all of these have their origins in handwritten logs of users who are accessing early systems.  They are all semantically equivalent and users will likely understand them equally.  I think it comes down to preference.  Just pick one and use it consistently.