# "Sign In" or "Log in" or "Login"

Tags: authentication, grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UI Terminology: Logon vs Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406016/ui-terminology-logon-vs-login)

Which is the right one to use

```
- Sign in
- Log in
- Login
```

Being a non-native English speaker it is difficult to distinguish them. I guess I should have asked at dictionary.com forum but I need a technical answer.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406016/ui-terminology-logon-vs-login

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Either of the first two are fine I'd say.

Not the third though - "Login" is a noun (if it is really a word at all): "What is your login?"

The other two are verbs "to sign in", or "to log in".

Comment: Does that mean we need to file a bug to change 'login' to 'log in' in SO?

Comment: Ha ha - hadn't noticed that. I think if we were trying to be really strict and gramatically correct then probably. In truth I don;t think it really matters as long as the intention is clear and unambiguous!

Comment: Don't even go there! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29229/use-of-login-logout-is-inconsistent-and-incorrect

Answer (score 14):

> Sign In

If you're dealing with an application/website that deals with people

E.g. Sign in to my space, sign in to my blog

> Log in

for other applications.

E.g. Log in to the system, Log in on your computer

Comment: It means in programs in the work 'Log in'? And in socal websites 'Sign In'?

Comment: In social websites, definitely Sign In (even internal). But systems where you need to do some work, such as, CRM, Financial software, Bank Account, etc I would use Log in

Comment: I got what you mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I've switched to using Sign In/Sign Out/Sign Up for my own apps on the basis that it's slightly less technical language than Log In/Log Out.

Answer (score 2):

Either "log in" or "sign in" is fine.

Just make sure you're consistent (see: [Login/Logout vs Sign In/Sign Out vs Log in/Sign out – A short roundup](http://bundlr.com/clips/528ab3fd71643e5cb400010f).

Comment: The link is broke(n) again... Gambling problem maybe? 
 
Maybe use this one, couldn't find the old article: 
https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/using-sign-in-vs-using-log-in